# How to Modularize and Customize a web application?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, architecture, frontend

My company has a product which was custom made according to the the specification provided by one of the client banks. Now since the product was a success another bank approached for the same we had to do bit of code changes so as to provide them with the customizations they required for their bank. Now the senario is that number of banks approaching us is insceasing every day and my team is looking forward to some kind of generalization so as to just configure the product at the time of delivery with minimal code changes.Now My questions are as follows:-

1. How to modularize the code so as to have perfect customization ?
2. How can we achieve customization for the front end so that different banks can configure it in accordance to their own needs?
3. Which templating and backend technologies are required so as to fill the gap for the above requirements.
4. For timebeing we have used localization so as to change the lables according to the customer but are there any better ways?
5. Is Drools or OSGI of any use if the application is to be delivered rapidly.
6. Validation of the different fields and other ui components are also required so as to cater the needs of specific banks? What are the solutions available for them?

NOTE:We are using Spring3 Mostly the MVC module to build the solution and are looking forward to some kind of industrial product which can be customizable and can be delivered with ease and even the process should be fast without steep learning curve.

Comment: Customizing a banking application and doing it rapidly?

Comment: drools is a rules engine. Any rules engine will definitely help if you want to run business rules. If all your rules logic is embedded in the code its time to look at a rules engine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy (one size fits all) solutions. The customizations range from cosmetic UI styling, to addition of new fields / relationships at the data model level, changes to business logic etc, changes to workflow.

The good way to handle this is to figure out what is constant across different implementation and what needs to be changed.  Go back and make the necessary changes to make it easier to customize those things by adding new code instead of modifying existing code (open close principle).  Selective use of a workflow engine, business rules engine can make certain kind of the customization easier.

The goal should be to strive to have a common code base with 70-80 % of the core features and then additional 15-20% implementation specific customization.

Approaches to build something that can be configured dynamically by using some drag and drop UI or even by XML / db configuration are usually a couple of orders of magnitude more complex than the approach where you have a well designed core module with hooks to allow customization by writing new code.

You can take a look at things like [OFBiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/), [OpenERP](http://www.openerp.com/) etc to get an idea of how to do it and how complex they tend to become.

You can also look at modern code generation frameworks like [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo/), [Sculptor](https://sites.google.com/site/fornaxsculptor/) etc that can help enable building a base product that can be easily customized by writing additional code.